# PHP Arrays and using Variable Variables to select the correct one

Tags: php, arrays

First post here and only just learning PHP, so sorry for what I'm about to ask.

I have a series of arrays with carefully structured names.  Within the preceding PHP I Identify the various sections of the name to and use that to create a string which matches the name of the array I need to reference, however I keep getting an array to string error when I try to indirectly address the array.

Is there a way to pass it across as an Array?

i.e.

```
$Array1A = Array(1,2,3,4);
$Array1B = Array(2,3,4,1);
$Array2A = Array(3,4,1,2);
$Array2B = Array(4,1,2,3);

$Var1 = '2';
$Var2 = 'A';
$ArrayToLookup = 'Array'.$Var1.$Var2; // Returns the String 'Array2A'

$ArrayToUse = ${$ArrayToLookup}; // I get an Array to String error here

$Answer = $ArrayToUse[2]; // I would want this to read off $Array2A[2]
```

Comment: PHP version you are using

Comment: I think this is valid code all the way back to 5.3

Comment: This code actually runs fine, i think what @ThienHuynh is saying is likely correct, the error is probably coming when you are trying to echo $ArrayToUse

Comment: I've been running in Ver 5.2. but this point has driven me crazy as I just cannot resolve the error.

Comment: I have just been off and tried it on a generic PHP tester and it works. So my issue is with my test server config I assume... I never thought to check it elsewhere before starting.

Comment: Wasn't the resolution I was expecting, but thank you @MHewison and mail2bapi

Comment: Try with php 7+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works in PHP 7.4, one thing I would suggest trying is double "$":

```
$Array1A = Array(1,2,3,4);
$Array1B = Array(2,3,4,1);
$Array2A = Array(3,4,1,2);
$Array2B = Array(4,1,2,3);

$Var1 = '2';
$Var2 = 'A';
$ArrayToLookup = 'Array'.$Var1.$Var2; // Returns the String 'Array2A'

$ArrayToUse = ${$ArrayToLookup}; // <- this works when tested on php 7.4
$ArrayToUse = $$ArrayToLookup; // <- this should work since its 10 years old

$Answer = $ArrayToUse[2]; // I would want this to read off $Array2A[2]

echo $Answer; // returns 1
```

Comment: I discovered it wasn't the php server config either, it was actually me posting an echo of the $ArrayToUse... So thank you again @MHewison.